# java.lang.Instantiation exception when unmarshalling XML file with Groovy, but in Java works

Tags: java, xml, groovy, xsd, jaxb

I have an XSD schema which defines a complex type hierarchy:

```xml
<xsd:complexType abstract="true" name="Node">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:extension base="core:DescribableElement">
            ...
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType abstract="true" name="SuccessorNode">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:extension base="test:Node">
            ...
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="StartNode">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:extension base="test:SuccessorNode">
            ...
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
<!-- other types omitted for brevity... -->
```

From this XSD schema, I have generated the corrisponding Java classes using Gradle jaxb plugin.

My problem is that when I try to unmarshal an XML file written according to this schema, in Groovy I get an error, but in Java it works correctly.

Java code:

```java
File xmlFile = new File("test.xml");
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(ObjectFactory.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
JAXBElement<Pipeline> element = (JAXBElement<Pipeline>) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlFile);
```

Groovy code:

```
def xmlFile = new File("test.xml")
def context = JAXBContext.newInstance(ObjectFactory.class)
def unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller()
def element = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlFile) as JAXBElement<Pipeline>
```

With the Groovy code, I get a `java.lang.InstantiationException`:

```
Caught: jakarta.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: Unable to create an instance of test.Node
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.InstantiationException]
jakarta.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: Unable to create an instance of test.Node
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.InstantiationException]
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:701)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:230)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.createInstance(UnmarshallingContext.java:665)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StructureLoader.startElement(StructureLoader.java:156)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.XsiTypeLoader.startElement(XsiTypeLoader.java:49)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:534)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:513)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:218)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:189)
    at jakarta.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:140)
    at jakarta.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:179)
    at jakarta.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:164)
    at Test.main(Test.groovy:13)
    at Test.run(Test.groovy:18)
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.core.v2.ClassFactory.create0(ClassFactory.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.createInstance(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:252)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.createInstance(UnmarshallingContext.java:659)
    ... 12 more
```

It seems that the Groovy code is unable to handle namespaces inside the `xsi:type` attribute, while the Java code handles them nicely:

- the Java code correctly instantiates the concrete classes;
- on the other hand, the Groovy code tries to instantiates the abstract one (and this it throws an exception since an abstract class cannot be instantiated)

Why does this happen? Is there a way to fix this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (assuming the package name is "test"):

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("test", test.ObjectFactory.class.getClassLoader());
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but your solution does not work. I still get the same error.